# wicked_pdf/wkhtmltopdf ignores Twitter Bootstrap css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

i am having trouble generating a pdf document in Ruby using wicked_pdf/wkhtmltopdf from the following sources:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.pdf {
    render :pdf => pdf_filename(@invoice,false),
        :template => "invoices/generate",
        :layout => "document",
        :show_as_html => params[:debug]
  }
end
```

--

```
  <style type='text/css'>/*!
  * Bootstrap v2.1.1
  ...
  */
    .clearfix{*zoom:1;}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;content:"";line-height:0;}
    .clearfix:after{clear:both;}
   /*.... and so on twitter bootstrap css is definitely included here ..... */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
   <div id="left" class="span6">
     <!-- any text here -->
   </div>
   <div id="right" class="span6">
     <!-- any other text here -->
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The generated PDF does ignore bootstraps css completely (meaning the whole layout of the document is scrambled). But it`s completely loaded into the "style" section.

When I try to debug (generate.pdf?debug=1) the output html I do get correct formatting as i wanted it to be (#left is a column on the left of the page, #right is a column on the right).

Is wkhtmltopdf capable of rendering twitter bootstrap css ?

I`m using latest wicked_pdf gem with wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc1.

Thank you for any hint on this !

Comment: did some further research with wkhtmltopdf only and found out that if the style of bootstrap is harcoded inline into <head> section into a <style> tag it`s ignored by wkhtmltopdf. If it`s linked using <link> tag it works. However, if i put some simple styles directly into a <style> tag they work, but bootstraps css not !

Comment: There's a great answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28048548/642616?stw=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind !!

Updating to the latest Bootstrap version 2.2.1 fixed it (had 2.1.1 prior). Dont ask me why but it must have been an issue in Bootstrap which i didn`t suspect.

Comment: seems to have something to do with formatting. Tried to use a customized version generated on bootstraps webpage. Used minified and non-minified version - no chance to get it working. Then downloaded sources and compiled it with LESS myself --> works like a charm.Strange.

Answer (score 4):

In your layout you must provide absolute paths in your CSS include tags OR use the provided helpers:

```
wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
```

Comment: hi, thx, i used the helper wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag which did copy bootstraps css as inline css into the source document. But this inline style was ignored by wkhtmltopdf :-/

Comment: Check your version of wkhtmltopdf.  I had issues with stuff in the apt repository and homebrew (on OSX)... just compiled it instead so I could get the latest version.

Comment: i`m on win (development), used prebuilt binary. No issues except this one. However, seems to be a formatting bug as far as i could find out (see below). Thank you anyway cpuguy !