# Wicked PDF ignores bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

in my template x.pdf.erb site i have linked all the stylesheets and javascript tags:

```
           <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.css" -%>
            <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "style.css" -%>
            <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "styleUmowa.css" -%>
            <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "animate.css" -%>
            <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

When the pdf site is generated, everything is good except bootstrap grid system, i mean wicked pdf ignores my:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
       <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
       <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So, it`s displayed like normal divs without bootstrap grid. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a hyphen in your final closing tag (`-%>` rather than `%>`)?

Comment: Yes, it should be there, i have already checked this. Even with bootstrap from CDN link <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: Everything except grid is working fine, but i need grid system most.

Comment: The bootstrap css contains a `@media print {` section to customize print rendering. It includes this css: `.navbar {display: none;}`.
 It's likely that this is your problem. Is the menu also missing if you print preview from your browser?

Comment: on my pdf there is no menu, but i will try it.

Comment: @update: I have added navbar element, and it`s fully visible on the pdf site.

Comment: @update: Problem probably solved, i was using "col-lg-x", but somehow the pdf site accepts only "col-xs-x" which i was not even trying out.

Comment: @KacperTrafiał That's a solution only for bootstrap 3. Bootstrap 4 does not have col-xs anymore and it just wont work

Comment: Good question, I got the same issue and i got sol'n from here.

Answer (score 67):

I've came across the same problem. There are several solutions:

1. [Upgrade](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) your `wkhtmltopdf` binary to version >= 0.12, then add `:viewport_size` option to render, something like this:

```ruby
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: "my_pdf",
           viewport_size: '1280x1024'
  end
end
```

2. Or you can just use `col-xs-*` classes
3. Or create `pdf.css.scss` (I'm  using bootstrap-sass) with following content:

```css
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

@include make-grid(sm);
@include make-grid(md);
@include make-grid(lg);
```

Don't forget to include it with `<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf.css" -%>`

For plain css you will have to copy-paste all `.col-sm-*`, `.col-md-*`, `.col-lg-*` rules from bootstrap.css into your pdf.css, BUT without `@media` wrappers, it's important.

Comment: Thanks for great and complete solution(s) :)

Comment: For some reason I cannot use the `.row` class with that pdf.css.scss you suggested. I know that the .row class isn't included (and honestly it isn't much of an issue to create one within it). I tried to simply include ALL of bootstrap 3 with `@import "bootstrap"` but this only allows me to use 10 columns.

Comment: Awesome answer!! Thanks so much. This should be marked correct. I went the "col-xs-*" route for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Great elegant solution with number 3. love it!

Comment: What about bootstrap 4?

Comment: This is called Perfect Answer, Thank you for the help!!

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.2 and Bootstrap 4 but I haven't been successful to make `wicked_pdf` gem work with styles from [boostrap gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem). Does anybody have any example to make it work?

Comment: I'm getting an "undefined mixin 'make-grid'" error with option #3, any ideas?

Comment: @AlexVentura I ended up downloading the bootstrap css to it's own css file and putting it in an AWS S3 bucket. Then linking to that CSS file in my pdf template file. Worked for me. But I had to set the viewport like above in the answer

Answer (score 13):

The above solutions don't work with Bootstrap 4 as of now. Bootstrap 4's grid system is built on the use of flexbox, which is not supported by wicked_pdf, due to its dependency on wkhtmltopdf.

In order to get a simple grid working while using Bootstrap 4, it's best to define your own grid by using the width `w-*` and display `d-*` commands, in order to overrule the `display: flex` setting.

Example:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row d-table-row">
       <div class="col w-25 d-table-cell"></div>
       <div class="col w-25 d-table-cell"></div>
       <div class="col w-25 d-table-cell"></div>
       <div class="col w-25 d-table-cell"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: only widths of 25, 50, 75 and 100% are supported by default. You can increase flexibility by adding your own additional width definitions to the `$sizes` variable of bootstrap, by adding something like this to your scss stylesheet:

```
// _custom.scss

@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
$sizes: map-merge((20: 20%, 33: 33.33%, 40: 40%, 60: 60%, 67: 66.67%, 80: 80%), $sizes);
@import "bootstrap";

// Your CSS
```

Using width and display classes:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

Bootstrap 4 flexbox grid and wkhtmltopdf:

[How to use flexboxgrid with wicked_pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638647/how-to-use-flexboxgrid-with-wicked-pdf)

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who using [KnpLabs/snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy), giving the viewport as an option fixes the situation:

```
$snappy->setOption('viewport-size','1280x1024');
```

Answer (score 2):

I came accross this solution, just add this to your css file, and it should work.

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
}
```

Comment: this worked for me - simple and elegant

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using pdfkit (python) which uses wkhtmltopdf. To use bootstrap's grid system, I'm using bootstrap 3.4.1 and bootstrap 5.1.3 (yes I'm importing both .min.css in the same HTML), so I can use grid system and the latest bootstrap components.

You need to use col-xs-<*number*> instead of col-<*number*> so the PDF will be exported correctly

I know it is not the best and probably optimal solution, but works!