# wicked_pdf only partially uses bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm generating a PDF in Rails using wicked_pdf. I've followed [instructions](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/wiki/Configuring-wicked_pdf-for-Bootstrap) on their wiki about how to include Bootstrap but with only partial success. I've also seen answers on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629710/wicked-pdf-ignores-bootstrap-grid-system/28048548?stw=2#28048548), but also without perfect results.

In debug mode, everything looks fine. But the PDF is missing background colours using helpers like .bg-danger and striped tables. However I have got the correct typography, layout/column helpers and things like .img-responsive. Also, the page numbers don't work; I'm not sure if that's related or not.

## controller extract

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    render :template => "report/report.html"
  end
  format.pdf do
    render  pdf: "report",
            template: 'report/report.html',
            layout: 'pdf',
            show_as_html: params[:debug].present?,
            footer: { right: '[page] of [topage]' },
            javascript_delay: 2000,
            page_size:  'A4',
            viewport_size: '1280x1024'
```

## layouts/pdf.html.haml

```
%html
  %head
    %meta{ 'content' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'http-equiv'=> 'content-type' }
    = wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf", media: "all"
    = wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "chartkick"
    = wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "number_pages"
  %body
    = yield
```

## pdf.sass

```
@import "helpers"
@import "font-awesome"

@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
@import "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap/mixins"

@include make-grid(sm)
@include make-grid(md)
@include make-grid(lg)

body
  background-color: white

.page-break
  display: block
  clear: both
  page-break-after: always
  page-break: always
```

Update -

I wonder whether this could be related to print media settings within bootstrap which [gets rid of all background colours](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L191). But setting the print_media_type to false in the [wicked_pdf settings](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#advanced-usage-with-all-available-options) doesn't make any difference.