# Wicked PDF on RAILS 5 ignores bootstrap 4 grid system

Tags: bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

I'm using Wicked PDF within a RAILS 5 system, it works - I get a PDF page in the browser - but it seems to be that it ignores the bootstrap 4 grid system and the font is much smaller than expected.

**controller code**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render(pdf: "carrier_out_file",
           viewport_size: '1280x1024',
           template: 'carriers/order_now_as_pdf')
  end
```

**view code**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset='utf-8'/>
     <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" %>
     <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" %>
     <!--    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <%=  wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "number_pages" %>

     </head>
      <body onload='number_pages'>

       <div id="content">
       ....
```

Comment: My guess is this: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#usage-conditions---important

Comment: yes, that the reason I used this: <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" %>

Comment: This answer from a similar question helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/56237878/3604050

Answer (score 3):

It is known issue that wkpdftohtml has limited support for flexbox based grid systems as it uses an old version of Qt WebKit. One option is to try switching your wkpdftohtml version to the latest edge version 
`gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge'`. Another option would be to rewrite parts of your html to use a table based system or even revert back to a float based grid system.

For more information see : https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1522

As for the font issue you may look into setting your wicked_pdf.rb config to include `disable_smart_shrinking: true` I hope this helps!